# First Column In Matrix All Zeroes, Except One Element

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to get the **first column** of this matrix to be **all zeroes**, **EXCEPT for the second element**.

\begin{bmatrix}3&2&-3&-2\\1&2&0&1\\-2&2&3&1\\0&-1&3&3\end{bmatrix}

I've managed to get all zeroes, except the first element, by adding onto the 1st column, the 3rd column, then the negative of the 4th column, like so:

\begin{bmatrix}3+-3+2\\1+0+-1\\-2+3+-1\\0+3+-3\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}

I can't see a way to achieve the same thing, but for the second element instead.

I can only add multiples of columns together, factor columns, or swap the first column with any other column.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio: the matrix is invertible, so its column space is all $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I hadn't considered the possibility sorry. It was more just a brainteaser exercise than anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the matrix in the question.

If $A=\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$, the matrix $MA$ is the column matrix obtained as the sum of $a$ times the 1st column, $b$ times the 2nd column, $c$ times the 3rd column and $d$ times the fourth column. For example, when $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$, we obtain $MA=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Knowing that, the question is equivalent to: is there a matrix $A$ such that $MA=b$ where $b=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ x \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $x\neq 0$?

The answer is yes since a computation shows that the determinant of $M$ is not $0$, so $MA=b \iff A=M^{-1}b$.

Precisely, $\det(M)=42$ and

$$M^{-1}
=
\frac{1}{42}
\begin{bmatrix}
21 & -15 & 3 & 18\\
0 & 12 & 6 & -6 \\
21 & -29 & 17 & 18\\
-21 & 33 & -15 & -6 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

so, if $x=1$, we obtain $A=\frac{1}{42}\begin{bmatrix} -15\\ 12\\ -29\\ 33\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks Taladris! I definitely apprecaite it